# How can I open a Bootstrap (5.2) modal with a specific tab selected, from a button?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm trying to open a Bootstrap (5.2) modal with a specific tab selected. The tab should be determined by which button is clicked on the home page ("Login" or "Sign Up").

I tried previous solutions, but they mostly use older versions of Bootstrap.

I'm a complete noob to JavaScript, so if your solution includes it please explain like I'm five.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <!-- Log In / Sign Up Buttons -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">

              <!-- Sign Up Button -->
              <button id="signup-button" type="button" href="#pills-signup" class="btn btn-primary float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#login-signup-modal">
                  Sign Up
              </button>

              <!-- Log In Button -->
              <button type="button" href="#pills-login" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#login-signup-modal">
                Log In
              </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Log In Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="login-signup-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
          
            <!-- Modal Body -->
              <div class="modal-body">

                <!-- Tab Headers -->
                <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-login-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-login" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-login" aria-selected="true">Log In</button>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                    <button class="nav-link" id="pills-signup-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-signup" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-signup" aria-selected="false">Sign Up</button>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab Content -->
                <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">

                  <!-- Log In Tab -->
                  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-login-tab">
                    <form method="POST">
                      <!-- form-label & form-control = bootstrap form layouts -->
                      {{ log_in_form.email.label(class="form-label") }}
                      {{ log_in_form.email(class="form-control") }}
                      <br>
                      {{ log_in_form.password.label(class="form-label")}}
                      {{ log_in_form.password(class="form-control") }}
                      <br>
                      {{ log_in_form.submit(class="btn btn-primary form-control") }}
                    </form>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Sign Up Tab -->
                  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-signup" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-signup-tab">
                    <form method="POST">
                      {{ sign_up_form.email.label(class="form-label") }}
                      {{ sign_up_form.email(class="form-control") }}
                      <br>
                      {{ sign_up_form.password.label(class="form-label")}}
                      {{ sign_up_form.password(class="form-control") }}
                      <br>
                      {{ sign_up_form.confirm_password.label(class="form-label")}}
                      {{ sign_up_form.confirm_password(class="form-control") }}
                      <br>
                      {{ sign_up_form.submit(class="btn btn-primary form-control") }}
                    </form>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize bootstrap events. I think the javascript part is short, so basically listening for event `show.bs.modal` of the modal (see bootstrap docs) and get the reference to the invoking button `event.relatedTarget` (see bootstrap docs) which had in the first place an `data-tab-id="ID-OF-TAB"` attribute. We take that attribute and get a reference to the tab. Finally we use the tabs method `show` to show the correct tab.

```js
const myModal = document.getElementById('login-signup-modal')

myModal.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', (ev) => {
  var invoker = ev.relatedTarget
  var selected_tab = invoker.getAttribute("data-tab-id")
  const tab_btn = document.querySelector('#' + selected_tab)
  const tab = new bootstrap.Tab(tab_btn)
  tab.show()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Log In / Sign Up Buttons -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">

      <!-- Sign Up Button -->
      <button id="signup-button" data-tab-id="pills-signup-tab" type="button" href="#pills-signup" class="btn btn-primary float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#login-signup-modal">
                  Sign Up
              </button>

      <!-- Log In Button -->
      <button type="button" data-tab-id="pills-login-tab" href="#pills-login" class="btn btn-outline-primary float-end" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#login-signup-modal">
                Log In
              </button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Log In Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="login-signup-modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Body -->
      <div class="modal-body">

        <!-- Tab Headers -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active" id="pills-login-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-login" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-login" aria-selected="true">Log In</button>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link" id="pills-signup-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-signup" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-signup" aria-selected="false">Sign Up</button>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab Content -->
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">

          <!-- Log In Tab -->
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-login-tab">
            <form method="POST">
              <!-- form-label & form-control = bootstrap form layouts -->
              {{ log_in_form.email.label(class="form-label") }} {{ log_in_form.email(class="form-control") }}
              <br> {{ log_in_form.password.label(class="form-label")}} {{ log_in_form.password(class="form-control") }}
              <br> {{ log_in_form.submit(class="btn btn-primary form-control") }}
            </form>
          </div>

          <!-- Sign Up Tab -->
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-signup" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-signup-tab">
            <form method="POST">
              {{ sign_up_form.email.label(class="form-label") }} {{ sign_up_form.email(class="form-control") }}
              <br> {{ sign_up_form.password.label(class="form-label")}} {{ sign_up_form.password(class="form-control") }}
              <br> {{ sign_up_form.confirm_password.label(class="form-label")}} {{ sign_up_form.confirm_password(class="form-control") }}
              <br> {{ sign_up_form.submit(class="btn btn-primary form-control") }}
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Took me a bit to figure out the JavaScript cause I'm a noob. But it's functioning as it should now. Cheers!